# Is there a way to get the recurrence string from a KendoUI Recurrence Editor?

Tags: kendo-ui, recurrence

Because I needed a custom setup for my scheduling setup, I am implementing separate Calendar, Scheduler, and RecurrenceEditor widgets. So far, everything has worked fine, but I can't get the parsed string from the RecurrenceEditor widget. I haven't seen a method to pull the rule as a string in the API documentation (nor is the RecurrenceEditor widget really documented there).

This is how I'm setting up the recurrenceEditor:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#recurrence-editor").kendoRecurrenceEditor({
    start: new Date(),
    change: function(e)
    {
      var editor = e.sender;

      // I want to get the recurrence rule string here.
    }
  });
});
```

I'm not seeing anything in Firebug that gives me a hint for the method or property I might try. So far, I've tried:

```
editor.ruleValue
editor.recurrenceRule
```

It looks like I have access to some of the information, but I didn't want to write my own selections-to-parseable-string method if I could get it from the recurrence editor itself.

**UPDATE:** When I set it up this way:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#recurrence-editor").kendoRecurrenceEditor({
    start: new Date(),
    edit: function(e)
    {
      var editor = e.sender;
      var recurrenceString = editor.RecurrenceRule;

      return recurrenceString;
    }
  });
});
```

The edit event never fires. Probably because I'm not implementing the recurrence editor as part of the Scheduler widget, but as a standalone widget on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Setup the recurrence editor in the Scheduler's edit event, it will fire the change event and the value property is the standard iCal Recurrence Rule.

Here's mine:

```
// Setup Recurrence Editor
// Telerik support recommends this method over the common inline script
// because it allows us to choose which recurrence editor.  However, it does
// break the MVVM two-way bindings, so the current value MUST be explicitly set
// on creation, and the change event must be handled.
var event = e.event,
    container = e.container,
    recurrenceEditor = container.find("#recurrenceEditor");

if (kendo.support.mobileOS === false) {
    recurrenceEditor.kendoRecurrenceEditor({
        start: new Date(e.event.start),
        value: e.event.recurrenceRule,
        timezone: self.scheduleConfig.timezone,
        messages: self.scheduleConfig.messages.recurrenceEditor,
        change: function (ev) {
            event.set("recurrenceRule", this.value());
        }
    });
} else {
    // The Mobile Recurrence Editor requires the parent kendo pane
    // be passed as a parameter, otherwise it will crash when the
    // user attempts to alter the frequency

    var pane = container.parent(".km-pane").data("kendoMobilePane");

    recurrenceEditor.kendoMobileRecurrenceEditor({
        start: new Date(e.event.start),
        value: e.event.recurrenceRule,
        timezone: self.scheduleConfig.timezone,
        messages: self.scheduleConfig.messages.recurrenceEditor,
        pane: pane,
        change: function(ev) {
            event.set("recurrenceRule", this.value());
        }
    });
}
```

And the HTML (inside the custom editor template)

```
 <div class="lineEntry" data-bind="invisible: recurrenceId">
    <div id="recurrenceEditor" name="recurrenceRule" data-bind="value: recurrenceRule" class="toInlineBlock">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get it from the event you are describing in the editor's event edit/creator modal. Once you get the event, it's just `.RecurrenceRule`, if memory serves, it's just `e.event.RecurrenceRule`

Fun fact, the standard used in that string is [RFC 5545 3.3.10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but both event and RecurrenceRule are undefined in the Javascript event info that is sent into the change event handler.

Comment: Can you try that code on the edit event just to see if it works, if you need it on the change event, we'll work backwards?

Comment: Edited my original question above (comments was too short). In short, the edit event doesn't fire with how I'm implementing the RecurrenceEditor widget.